# Sort Multiple Arrays in java based on one int array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Here is the thing:

I have four different arrays with entities related to indexes. I mean `array1[i]` is related to `array2[i]`, `array3[i]` and `array4[i]`. I want to sort these arrays based on `array4[]` which is `int` type. So I implement an Entity class:

```
public class EntityObject implements Comparable<EntityObject>  {

    String value;
    String date;
    String cat;
    int index;


    EntityObject(String value, String date, String cat, int index){
        this.cat = cat;
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }
```

And in my main class I have:

```
  EntityObject[] array = new EntityObject[entry];
  for(int i = 0; i < entry; i ++){
      array[i] = new EntityObject(valueDB[i], dateDB[i], catDB[i], catIndexDB[i]);
  }
```

Now I want to sort my `array` of `EntityObject` based on `catIndexDB[]` which is `int` type. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finish by implementing `compareTo(EntityObject o)` from the Comparable interface.  Documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Then call `Arrays.sort(yourArray)` to sort your array of EnityObjects

Comment: Thank you but when I want to add this method into my object I have got error :"Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

Comment: you need to compare to another EntityObject not an int.  Change your parameter type

Answer (score 0):

If you add a getIndex method

```
public int getIndex(){
    return index;
}
```

in your class EntryObject, you can sort your array with any sorting algorithm you want to use by comparing

```
array[i].getIndex();
```

Otherwise you can make EntryObject Comparable and use `Arrays.sort(array)`